# How to mix small and large colored highlights using strobes?

Tags: lighting, reverse-engineering, strobes, strobist

I'm trying to get better with handling multiple strobes and with adding in color effects. The image below was taken with a single strobe held high above the camera and bounced off the ceiling:

[image]

This is a version that I tweaked in a photo editor:

[image]

I can adjust the white balance in camera to get the overall cooler feel straight out of the camera but I have been unsuccessful in getting the purple light from my strobe to appear as a soft color tint on the right. I like how the purple fades into red moving toward the right - and the only thing I can think to do would be to use a larger red light and a snooted or gridded purple light...

But, I've only got 2 strobes, so that may be part of the problem...So, brownie points if your techniques allow me to recreate the shot successfully using just the two. What do you suggest I do to recreate this shot fully (or at least *mostly*) in camera?

Answer (score 1):

The "pro" option. Use color gels. There are some well-known brands like Rosco and Lee

http://www.leefilters.com/lighting/colour-list.html

https://rosco.com/products/catalog/roscolux

You could buy some multiple colores collection of small pieces. I prefer buying the full sheet because I do not use that many colors.

Google "colored gels for flash".

---

Some casual options

You can use any colored plastic or transparent or translucent material. A Plastic bag, a transparent plastic bag painted with markers, some plastic containers.

Or you can bounce the flash you want to a matt colored surface, like a colored paper. You can paint some cards using acrylic paint and use them as bounce colored cards.

---

Set the white balance for the main white light.

Comment: Always feel free to edit my ignorance translated into a post :o)

Comment: This is offtopic, but I found the word in different dictionaries, so probably it is not used that often, or it is used in some other regions. http://www.yourdictionary.com/translucid